# NHibernate uses value from the first query

Tags: nhibernate

So, I have a query like

```
public static IEnumerable<Archive> GetArchivesRecursive(this ISession session, Page rootPage)
{
    var archives = session.Query<Page>().Where(p => p != rootPage && p.Path.StartsWith(rootPage.Path))
    .GroupBy(p => new { Year = p.Published.Year, Month = p.Published.Month })
    .Select(g => new Archive
    {
            ContextPageId = rootPage.Id,
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            Month = g.Key.Month,
            TotalPageCount = g.Count(),
            PublicPageCount = g.Count(p => p.State == PageState.Public && p.Published <= DateTime.UtcNow)
    })
    .ToList();

    // ContextPageId has old value (id of the first rootPage used since app start)
    // Why do I have to do this?
    archives.ForEach(a => a.ContextPageId = rootPage.Id);
    return archives;
}
```

For some reason ContextPageId property gets value of the first rootPage parameter that was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, quite interesting, my NH 3.2 actually fails with `MismatchedTreeNodeException` for even simplier queries when trying to have value from input in `Select` inside query. Which version are you using?

Anyway, looks like you just can't use values from outside the query in projection (`Select`) and this is probably NHibernate's Linq limitation. Your version seems to cache the compiled expression from `Select` ignoring the fact that it depends from a variable. `DateTime` value is the same for all calls, too, isn't it?

A bit cleaner workaround could go like this:

```
.Select(g => new
{
    Year = g.Key.Year,
    Month = g.Key.Month,
    TotalPageCount = g.Count(),
    PublicPageCount = g.Count(p => p.State == PageState.Public && p.Published <= DateTime.UtcNow)
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(g => new Archive
{
    ContextPageId = rootPage.Id,
    Year = g.Year,
    Month = g.Month,
    TotalPageCount = g.TotalPageCount,
    PublicPageCount = g.PublicPageCount
})
.ToList();
```

**EDIT** I've looked a bit more carefully and this indeed is a NHibernate bug, already known. See [this blog post](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2011/11/linq-pitfalls-using-external-variables.html) and [this JIRA bug entry](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2500).

Comment: NH version seems to be 3.2.0.4000, installed via nuget. I guess I have to check that DateTime part also.